# Как реализовывать связи между Model, View и Presenter + Room?

Tags: java, android, mvp, room

Не могу понять как реализовать связь в MVP + Room.

На примере приложения "Заметки":

Я создал БД с использованием Room.

```
@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class NotesDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static NotesDatabase database;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "notes.db";
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public static NotesDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        synchronized (LOCK){
            if (database == null) {
                database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, NotesDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                        .build();
            }
        }
        return database;
    }

    public abstract NotesDao notesDao();
}
```

Создал Model, в которой находятся запросы к БД

```
public class MainModel{

    private static NotesDatabase database;

    private LiveData<List<Note>> notes;

    public MainModel(Application application) {
        database = NotesDatabase.getInstance(application);
        notes = database.notesDao().getAllNotes();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void deleteAllNote() {
        new DeleteNotesTask().execute();
    }

    public void insertNote(Note note) {
        new InsertTask().execute(note);
    }

    public void deleteNote(Note note){
        new DeleteTask().execute(note);
    }

    public Note getNoteById(int id) {
        try {
            return new GetNoteTask().execute(id).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void updateNote(Note note) {
        new UpdateTask().execute(note);
    }

    private static class DeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
            if (notes != null && notes.length > 0) {
                database.notesDao().deleteNote(notes[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class DeleteNotesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            database.notesDao().deleteAllNote();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class InsertTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
            if (notes != null && notes.length > 0) {
                database.notesDao().insertNote(notes[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class GetNoteTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Note> {

        @Override
        protected Note doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            if (integers != null && integers.length > 0) {
                return database.notesDao().getNoteById(integers[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
            if (notes != null && notes.length > 0) {
                database.notesDao().updateNote(notes[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

И дальше совсем не понятно как это все связать между собой и к тому же со View and Presenter.

Пытался написать Presenter, но абсолютно нет понимания как это сделать правильно.
Пример Presenter:

```
public class MainPresenter {

    private MainModel model;
    private NotesAdapter adapter;
    private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();



    public void getData() {
        LiveData<List<Note>> notesFromDb = model.getNotes();
        notesFromDb.observe([что писать в качестве owner?], new Observer<List<Note>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Note> notesFromLiveData) {
                notes.clear();
                notes.addAll(notesFromLiveData);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с вопросом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть MVP (Model View Presenter). Классическая схема выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Давайте разберем, что здесь и как работает. У нас есть 3 основные сущности:

- **View** - это некий **UI** (чаще всего это ваш `Fragment` или `Activity`) единственной задачей которого является рисовать интерфейс для пользователя и сообщать о действиях пользователя `Presenter-у`. **View** должна быть тупой до безобразия, в ней не должно быть никакой логики, она не должна уметь сама что-то считать или получать какие-либо данные. Только **рисовать** и **сообщать о действиях пользователя** `Presenter-у`.
- **Presenter** - это собственно сущность которая отвечает за логику. Именно здесь происходят какие-то расчеты, именно здесь решается что показать пользователю, именно здесь решается как отреагировать на действия пользователя.
- **Model** - это любая сущность которая отвечает за данные. Часто это [Repository](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-repository-%D0%B2-android-a561d4bbd9ee), но это может быть и ваша база данных и `Retrofit` (или любая другая сущность отвечающая за походы в сеть). Задача **Model-и** предоставлять данные. Только **Model** знает откуда они приходят.

Нужно понимать, что **View** имеет в себе ссылку на **Presenter** и понятия не имеет о существовании **Model-и**. **Presenter** знает о **Model-и** и имеет ссылку на интерфейс **View**. **Model** вообще не знает ни о ком и ни от кого не зависит. Она не зависит ни от чего. В данной схеме это самый верхний уровень, в то время как **View** - самый нижний уровень, который зависит от других уровней.

Теперь поговорим о взаимодействии этих сущностей:

Допустим у нас есть экран авторизации. На этом экране есть 2 поля ввода (логин и пароль) и кнопка "авторизоваться". Пользователь вошел в приложение, ввел свой логин и пароль и нажал кнопку.

1. **View** считала данные из двух полей ввода и вызвала у **Presenter-a** метод
   `presenter.login(login, password);`
2. **Presenter** проверил данные на валидность (например, чтоб в логине не было символов) и обратился к модели
   `model.auth(login, password);`
   Метод к примеру возвращает `callback` с ответом (`onResponse()`, `onFailure()`)
3. **Model** сходила на сервер, проверила там данные и вернула ответ который и прилетит в `callback` который вы реализуете в **Presenter-e**, например все ок и мы упадем в `onResponse()`
4. В **Presenter-e** в `onResponse()` мы получаем ответ с данными о пользователе и хотим открыть второй экран. Здесь мы обращаемся к интерфейсу **View** `view.openNextScreen(userData)`
5. Наша **View** реализует интерфейс с которым работает **Presenter** и при вызове метода `openNextScreen()` в **Presenter-e** она вызывает  `startActivity(...)`.

Это простой пример на пальцах что такое MVP и как это все между собой взаимодействует. Есть очень много разных реализаций, но сводится все примерно к такому флоу.

Накину несколько ссылок для более подробного изучения:

- [Мой старенький MVP шаблонный проект](https://github.com/industradamus/TextMvpApplication). Здесь нет **Model-и** но есть взаимодействие **Presenter-a** с **View**, а **Model** прикрутить не сложно.
- [Android MVP пример для начинающих. Без библиотек и интерфейсов](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/493-mvp-dlja-nachinajuschih-bez-bibliotek-i-interfejsov.html).
- [MVP в Android на примере экрана с пин кодом](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/473-mvp-na-primere-jekrana-s-pin-kodom.html).
- MVP в Android приложении: [Часть 1](https://medium.com/@skidanolegs/mvp-%D0%B2-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1-9b08c46559fc); [Часть 2](https://medium.com/@skidanolegs/mvp-%D0%B2-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2-2b9587c0faf4); [Часть 3](https://medium.com/@skidanolegs/mvp-%D0%B2-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-3-780cffb0deec). Здесь отличное и обширное описание MVP в андроиде.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Вы мне очень помогли! Только первая ссылка не рабочая, поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Рабочая, просто забыл, что он приватный. Попробуйте еще, сделал публичным.

Comment: все работает, спасибо.